# Insert text object beautifulsoup to html element

Tags: html, css, text, beautifulsoup, insert

i'm beginner. Now i want insert text to  by beautifulsoup.
i try `soup.h1.string = "abc"` but it for first `h1` tag.
i want all `h1` tag in file html change the text. i'm sorry my english not good. thank for help !

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<body>
<h1>1</h1>
<h1>2</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You do it with basic loop:

```
txt = '''<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<body>
<h1>1</h1>
<h1>2</h1>
</body>
</html>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

for h1 in soup.select('h1'):    # for every h1 found in soup...
    h1.string = 'abc'           # ...set text of this h1 to 'abc'

print(soup)
```

Prints:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<body>
<h1>abc</h1>
<h1>abc</h1>
</body>
</html>
```